# How to log SSL/TLS Handshake details on Google Cloud Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-load-balancer

In order to identify what TLS version our clients are connecting with, I need to log details about the SSL/TLS handshake on a Google Cloud Load Balancer (GKE Ingress).

Logging the TLS/SSL version would be a great first step. I will need to identify which user the request is coming from in a second step.

By default, only the `httpRequest` is logged but contains no information about the handshake.

```
httpRequest: {
 latency: "0.077152s"
 remoteIp: "1.2.3.4"
 requestMethod: "POST"
 requestSize: "256988"
 requestUrl: "https://api.foo.bar/v1.0/foo"
 responseSize: "22746"
 serverIp: "1.2.3.4"
 status: 200
 userAgent: "axios/0.20.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the tls info via custom headers: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/custom-headers?authuser=1#variables. You'll need to log these on your own.

Comment: Awesome, thank you @Mbrevda! Looks like this is now available and without your answer I would have missed that. I logged {tls_version} and {tls_cipher_suite} and got the information I was looking for.